# No data inserted with this WHERE NOT EXISTS expression?

Tags: postgresql, upsert, if-not-exists

I want to move data from MySQL to PostgreSQL. I am using mysql.connector and psycopg2 for querying the two databases. When I run `WHERE NOT EXISTS` for my PostgreSQL DB, it's doesn't insert the data from MySQL.

The subject table doesn't have a unique column so I am using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` instead of `ON CONFLICT`.

```
curr_msql.execute('''SELECT scode, sname sunits FROM subject_table''')

 for row in curr_msql:
            curr_pgsql.execute('''INSERT INTO subject (created, modified, code, name, units)
            SELECT current_timestamp, current_timestamp, %s, %s, %s
            WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT code FROM subject WHERE code = code)
            ''', (row['scode'], row['sname'], row['sunits']))
```

I am not getting any error when running the query but the data are not getting inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition compares the column value to itself:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT code FROM subject WHERE code = code)
```

Boils down to:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT FROM subject WHERE code IS NOT NULL)
```

IOW, it's *always* `true` as soon as there is a single row in the table with `code IS NOT NULL`. I don't think that's intended.

Guess you want something like:

```
'''INSERT INTO subject (created, modified, code, name, units)
   SELECT current_timestamp, current_timestamp, %s, %s, %s
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT code FROM subject WHERE code = %s)'''
, (row['scode'], row['sname'], row['sunits'], row['scode']))
```

And that's not fit for concurrent write load. I suggest to create the missing `UNIQUE` constraint on `(code)` and use `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT ... DO NOTHING` if at all possible. If the table is big, you'll want an index on `code` for performance, anyway.